# mongoDB FTDC disable or not during normal operation?

Tags: mongodb

Is it worth to disable the mongod FTDC(Full Time Diagnostic Data Capture) data collection and generation via:

```
 setParameter:
     diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled: false
```

that generate the stats files in the folder: diagnostic.data

Do we gain some additional memory and cpu by doing so?

In the [official docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/)  they say:

These defaults are designed to provide useful data to MongoDB Inc. engineers with minimal impact on performance or storage size.

But if my system is in good shape do I need to collect this data at all, please, advice?